# Usage of Eclipse DLTK parser in a stand alone application for python

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to implement error checking rules for lint styled static analysis of simple codes (single function, about 30-100 lines) in c, cpp, java and python. The main requirement for solving this is being able to generate ASTs.

I observed that the Eclipse IDE does a lot of static analysis, AST generation and processing using the plugins CDT, JDT, DLTK. I found that JDT could be used in standalone applications not requiring Eclipse to generate ASTs. However I wasn't able to find a working demo for a standalone implementation using DLTK.

Is it possible to use it without having Eclipse or the editor modules running to generate and process ASTs? Any suggestions on their usage/implementation? Could this be done by any other library, perhaps PyDev?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the PyDev code is able to do the linting without having a running Eclipse instance...

You may want to take a look at the test-cases which do that in a standalone manner:

https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/tests/com/python/pydev/analysis/OccurrencesAnalyzerTest.java

The major thing is how the test-case does the setup so that it can recognize the PYTHONPATH, but after that's setup, it should be straightforward -- you can do a debug session and see what actually happens there :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't DLTK think can be used "standalone", not in the same sense of JDT, since they list the Eclipse Platform, EMF, and ANTLR runtime as prerequisiteson their [download page](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/downloads/drops/R4.0/R-4.0-201206120903/). If you mean can it be used without a "workbench" or "workspace", I do not know, but if that is possible, you could determine that, and "create your own collection" of bundles, based on the Manifest files of their core plugins. But, I've never seen a demo of using it that way, so, sort of doubt it. (Or, at least doubt it would be easy. :)